# Finding instances of specifically ordered sequence in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pattern-matching

Suppose we have a list of integers given as follows:

```
ls = [1,5,10,11,12,20,26,31,32,33,34]
```

- Is there a way we can quickly find all occurrences (in terms of their indices) of 3 consecutive integers in the list where they increment by 1? The input lists are already sorted.

That is, in the above example we have 3 such occurrences, whose indices are:

- `[2,3,4]`, `[7,8,9]` and `[8,9,10]` which correspond to elements `[10,11,12]`, `[31,32,33]` and `[32,33,34].`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```py
matching = []

for i in range(len(ls)):
    sub_ls = ls[i:i+3]
    deltas = [nb-sub_ls[_index] for _index, nb in enumerate(sub_ls[1:])]
    if deltas == [1, 1]:
        matching.append((i, i+1, i+2))
```

Output:

```
[(2, 3, 4), (7, 8, 9), (8, 9, 10)]
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_.

Answer (score 1):

```
def check(ls):
    for i in range(len(ls)-1):
        if ls[i+1] != ls[i] + 1:
            return False
    return True

result = [[i+j for j in range(3)] for i in range(len(ls)-2) if check(ls[i:i+3])]
```

Alternate answer with a list comprehension!

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solutions comes to my mind is to iterate over the list in subset of 3 elements and check the condition.

```py
n = 3 #Number of elements in subset of list, in your question it's 3
x = [1,5,10,11,12,20,26,31,32,33,34]
for i in range(len(x)-n+1):
    a, b, c = x[i:i+n]
    if b-a == c-b == 1:
        print('indices->',list(range(i, i+n)), 'values->', x[i: i+n])
```

**output:**

```py
indices-> [2, 3, 4] values-> [10, 11, 12]
indices-> [7, 8, 9] values-> [31, 32, 33]
indices-> [8, 9, 10] values-> [32, 33, 34]
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_